# Explicit determination of lift of maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^1$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ be smooth with $\gamma(0) = 1$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is simply connected, $\gamma$ lifts to a unique continuous map $\widetilde{\gamma} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\widetilde{\gamma}(0)=0$ and $e^{2 \pi i \widetilde{\gamma}(t)} = \gamma(t)$.

Is there a "nice" description of $\widetilde{\gamma}$ in terms of $\gamma$ directly? Of course, $\widetilde{\gamma}$ is the principal argument of $\gamma$ up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$, but I would appreciate a nice single (explicit) expression, in terms of $\gamma$. Perhaps involving an integral.

Comment: It is $$\overline \gamma(t)=\frac1i\int_{\gamma_{|[0,t]}}\frac{dz}z=\frac1i\int_0^t\frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)}\,ds$$ for $t\geq 0.$ You have to muck about with signs for $t<0.$ The right integral is probably find there, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it is the kind of answer you are looking for, but if you view $S^1$ as $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}$ and use the fact that the multivalued function $\mathrm{Log}$ has derivative $1/z$, then since $\gamma(0)=1$,
$$
a(t) = \Im\left(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)} ds\right) = \frac{1}{i}\left(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)} ds\right)
$$
will give you a lift of $\gamma$. Indeed this is easy to check directly: if
$$
\frac{\gamma(t)}{\exp(ia(t))} = \gamma(t).\exp(-ia(t)) 
$$
satisfies
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma(t).\exp(-ia(t))) &= (\gamma'(t)-ia'(t))\exp(ia(t)) \\
&=\gamma'(t)\exp(-ia(t))-\gamma(t).\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}.\exp(ia(t))\\
&=(\gamma'(t)-\gamma'(t)).\exp(-ia(t)) = 0,
\end{split}
$$
and by assumption $\gamma(0)=1=\exp(ia(0))$, so that $\gamma(t)=\exp(ia(t))$ for all $t$.